# Please describe how to upgrade cakephp version 0.2.9

Tags: cakephp

Please describe how to upgrade cakePhp  version 0.2.9 to any latest version of cakephp .

Comment: There is no official migration guide/support for this version. There is also no sense in trying to convert Cake 0.x code to the current standards. That would take so much time, it makes more sense to redo the project in the latest CakePHP version (currently 3.0).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this is the cakephp version you want to update?
The current version of Cake 2.0 in `/path/to/cake/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`. The txt file contains a commented block stating that it has been there **since Cake 0.2.9**, followed by the actual version number.

The same file may be found in Cake 1.3 in `/path/to/cake/cake/VERSION.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

0.2.9 is not your cake php version.Its a first version of cake php that is written like @since CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9.You can find your cake php version just go to the path cake/lib/Cake/VERSION.txt.In last line of version.text you will find your cake php version. t's easy to miss, but it should just be a number, e.g. 1.3.8."